# Images not showing on webpage

Tags: express

my directory structure:
`
Root

- backend

  - app.js
- client

  - public

    - logo.jpg
    - banner.jpg
  - index.html
    `

in app.js:

```
 app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + "./../"+'/public'))
 app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'index.html'))
 })
```

in index.html:

```
        .image{
            background: url("./public/logo.jpg") no-repeat;
            height: 132px;
            width: 371px;
            margin-left: 38rem;
        }
        .image2{
            margin-top: 0;
            background: url("./public/banner.png") no-repeat;
            height: 131px;
            width: 1500px;
            margin-left: 40px;
            margin-right: 30px;
        }
```

Images are not displayed on webpage. I am getting error
`GET http://localhost:3000/public/banner.png 404 (Not Found) GET http://localhost:3000/public/logo.jpg 404 (Not Found)`